# how to split <p><span>Hello</span></p> to <span>Hello</span> using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

how to split `<p><span>Hello</span></p>` to `<span>Hello</span>` using javascript

```
var text = "<p><span>Hello</span></p>";
```

remember:I don't know what contain `<p>`, I don't know if `<p>` has any attribute or not

**I found the answer !**

```
var patt=/^<p.*?>(.*)<\/p>$/i;
var result=patt.exec(text);
alert(result[1]);
```

thank's ring0 & w3schools
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

but there is problem ! it doesn't work with

```
aa<p><span>Hello</span></p>aa
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave more than one example. Right now my answer would be `text = "<span>Hello</span>";`. Are you trying to remove paragraph tags, the most outer tag, all outer tags, or something else?

Comment: yes i want remove <p> tag but i don't know if <p> has any attribute or not

Comment: If it has an attribute then a DOM solution would probably be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression that takes care of removing `p` attributes

```
var new = text.replace(/^<p[^>]*>(.*)<\/p>$/i, "$1");
```

Or a version with `.*?`

```
var new = text.replace(/^<p.*?>(.*)<\/p>$/i, "$1");
```

And if `<pre>` or `<param>` may start the `text`, you have to prevent a match

```
var new = text.replace(/^<p\b.*?>(.*)<\/p>$/i, "$1");
```

**edit** to answer your second question

To remove whatever is before / after

```
var new = text.replace(/^.*<p\b[^>]*>(.*)<\/p>.*$/i, "$1");
```

But if you want to remove all `<p...>` and all `</p>`, you should use the two lines

```
var new = text.replace(/<p\b.*?>/ig, "");
new = text.replace(/<\/p>/ig, "");
```

Comment: See my question again.I will accept your answer if you complete it.

Comment: And added the `\b` that was missing in the last answer :-)

Answer (score 12):

Don't do string manipulations on this, make use of the DOM.

```
// create a dummy container div element
var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
// insert the desired html inside this container
tempDiv.innerHTML = "<p><span>Hello</span></p>";
// find the first para, and get its html
tempDiv.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML; // contains "<span>Hello</span>"
```

[Try this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/PhSMk/).

If you are using a framework like jQuery, you can use:

```
$("<p><span>Hello</span></p>").html()
```

[Try this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/kPj73/).

Comment: @Josh k - The solution doesn't insert into the DOM; it _creates_ a DOM element, but doesn't insert it.

Comment: and you downvoted me because you think `split` is cool? really? really? ok now let's also add a class - `<p class="wtf"><span>Hello</span></p>`. go split now.

Comment: Clearly the best solution is to use a regular expression ;)

Comment: @Anurag: I downvoted you because it didn't answer his question (as phrased), how do I split `[phase]`. He made no mention of using classes, so why should I care? Considering the updated answer, this solution is good. Upvoted.

Comment: @Josh - The OP did say `split` in his question, but reading more about it, he was not literally referring to the function, but rather chopping the paragraph tags out of that string, which can be achieved in numerous ways, and none of them would be clearly wrong.

Comment: It's a `split`... no, it's a `regex`... no, it's `jQuery`!

Answer (score 0):

What do you really want?

- You can pull this out with a substring: `text.substr(3, 18)`
- You can use a regex: `text.match(/<span>([^<]+)<\/span>/)`
- You can stick this is the DOM and parse it out.

You'll need to explain the question better.

Answer (score -1):

Note I used `p>` and `</p` instead of the full tag. I'm not sure if the split will give you an array with an empty first index if you use the full tag. I'm too lazy to test it given the rather poor question phrasing.

```
var text = "<p><span>Hello</span></p>";
var foo = text.split("p>");
var bar = foo[1].split("</p");
alert(bar[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but if <p> has any attribute, what can i do.
can you split using <p not p>